# How do you get an Enderman?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

My brother is playing Minecraft for the xbox 360 and he has heard about Enderman but he can't find any. I keep trying to find a website that has the answer to my question, but we don't know if you have to do something before you can get one or if you have to go look for it. (Sorry, we just got the game so we don't know very much about it.)

Answer (score 10):

Unfortunately, Endermen do not currently exist in the Xbox version of Minecraft, though they are (presumably) planned (along with everything else the PC version has the Xbox version hasn't).

The PC version of Minecraft is (at the time of this writing) release version 1.2.5, [the Xbox version is roughly beta 1.6](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Xbox_360_Edition#Version), and Endermen were added in beta 1.8.

Comment: Minecraft for XBox was recently updated to ~1.7.3. No word yet on when it will be updated to beta 1.8.

Answer (score 2):

Endermen are being added to the XBox Edition sometime this month. In the 1.8.2 update. Many people expect it to be around the 25, give or take a few days.

Answer (score -3):

I have never found a single endermen on minecraft but in order to see endermen you have to play on the pc or I pod. To find him you have to either go in caves(dark) or very large desert regions. As many as 1 or 2 enderman spawn.

Comment: Incorrect.  Endermen spawn at any light level, so it's an issue of height.  As long as areas that have 3 blocks of space open, Endermen can spawn.

Comment: @Retrosaur Incorrect correction. [Endermen spawn only in the dark](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Endermen): *"[…] they still require a light level of seven or less in order to spawn."*

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Correct correction of an incorrect correction to an incorrect answer on a corrected question.